# how to use selenium webdriver in c#.net2

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I want to develop an application with c#.net2 that uses selenium web driver for filling text boxes of a web page in firefox that fetch from data base.but I can't find selenium driver for this version of .net(.Net fframework2).please help me.thanxs (Excuse me,my english is very bad!)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Any specific reason you want to use the old .NET framework 2 ? Or are you talking about .NET Core ? Anyway, I just created a console app and was able to add the Selenium Webdriver via Nuget Package in Visual Studio.